# Instantiating a View on iOS-NSException Caught while animating an array of images

Tags: ios, nsarray

Ken View is a name of a IBOutlet JBKenView *kenView
I connected this to a UIView

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
// NSArray *collage = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"collage1.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"collage 2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"collage 3.png"],nil];
self->kenView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
self->kenView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;


//img.animationImages=collage;
// img.animationDuration=8.0;
//img.animationRepeatCount=0;
//[img startAnimating];
btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:100.0/255 green:260.0/255 blue:183.0/255 alpha:1.0];
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[text2 setInputView:datePicker];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)text2.inputView;

picker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
NSArray *myImages = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"collage1.jpg"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"collage2.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"collage3.png"],];



[kenView animateWithImages:myImages
        transitionDuration:6
              initialDelay:0
                      loop:YES
               isLandscape:YES];

}
```

Implementing this gives an error:

```
2016-01-22 17:11:10.022 alumini2[29528:1325602] -[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8c31f2c700
2016-01-22 17:11:10.026 alumini2[29528:1325602] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8c31f2c700'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107c22885 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010769bdf1 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107c2ab5d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b77e3a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b779e8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   alumini2                            0x0000000106d413c2 -[FirstViewController viewDidLoad] + 706
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010814bd65 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 860
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010814c0b4 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010802f3d4 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 61
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010802fad1 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 302
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000108040ff8 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 43
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000107fc302b -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3545
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000107fc8ef0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1755
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000107fc673f -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    14  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010cda8d7b FrontBoardServices + 163195
    15  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010cda9118 FrontBoardServices + 164120
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b4d0f1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b42eac __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b42363 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107b41d78 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000107fc6091 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000107fca79b UIApplicationMain + 171
    22  alumini2                            0x0000000106d4481f main + 111
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001095efa05 libdyld.dylib + 10757
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: I am sorry About the editing i can't edit the question
I am very sorry , Please help!

Comment: Your crash doesn't seem to be related with animation of images... Check the type of object that you are setting delegate to... Your crash report says it is UIView, but UIView does not respond to `setDelegate:` method itself, unless it is a subclass that does. I guess you do that somewhere else in your file